# Solving $S=a_1x_1+a_2x_2+.....+a_nx_n.$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

is there solution possible to the equation $S=a_1x_1+a_2x_2+.....+a_nx_n$?
$a_i,x_i,n$ belongs to Natural numbers. $a_i$ and $n$ are fixed and specified. while $x_i$ are variable. An answer need not be determined but how can we know whether it exists or not?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: For a solution in natural numbers the answer depends on how the $a_i$ share common factors and on how small $S$ is. Someone may provide an answer, or you can try to work one out from information at   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm#The_case_of_more_than_two_numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Geometric Interpretation:**

For real valued $x$ you can interpret this geometrically as a hyperplane $H$:
$$
a^\top x = S
$$
with normal vector $a$ and (signed) distance $d=S/\lVert a\rVert$ to the origin.

It depends on $a$ and $S$ if there are natural number valued $x$ on $H$.

[image: no solution]

The above example shows $n=3$ and the hyperplane $x + y + z = 2$, thus $a=(1,1,1)$ and $S=2$. Also shown are the points from $\{1,2,3\}^3 \subset \mathbb{N}^3$. No intersection, no solution.

[image: three soltions]

Now the same for $x + y + z = 4$. We now have three points intersecting.

**Combinatoric Interpretation:**

A combinatoric interpretation, if $S \in \mathbb{N}$, is about the composition of $S$ into $n$ parts with parts from $\mathbb{N}$:
$$
C_\mathbb{N}(n, S)
$$
A member of the composition set can be viewed as the result of filling
the $S-1$ intermediate gaps ("$\sqcup$")
$$
\overbrace{1 \sqcup 1 \sqcup 1 \dotsb 1 \sqcup 1 }^S
$$
with either a "$+$" or a separating "$\mid$" symbol. We have $n-1$ separators to place, which gives $\binom{S-1}{n-1}$ possibilities.

For the second example this would be $\binom{4-1}{3-1}=\binom{3}{2}=3!/(2!1!) = 3$.